# Level order insertion into a binary tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Suppose we are given a level order traversal output. How to construct a binary tree from that populated with the data at correct positions?

Please note that I'm not trying to sketch the tree from the given traversal output, but read off the traversal data from an array then populate a binary tree with it by actual coding in C.

Eg:

Let a[] = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G};  //the traversal output in an array

So level-order tree will look like this:

```
            A
           / \ 
          B   C
        / \  / \
       D   E F  G
```

Suppose there is a tree node structure like so:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}tree;
```

Now I'm trying to read a[] values and code this tree so that it looks like the diagram. There are many examples of level-order *traversal* but couldn't find anything relevant on actual coding for binary tree *construction*. This is sort of a "reverse of traversal".

Also please note that this is not homework, though I don't have problems tagging it if more people will notice it that way. :)

Comment: It sounds to me like the easiest mechanism would be to store the incoming data into a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). Is the incoming data suitable for the heap properties? Or is the tree a binary search tree?

Comment: Strange... usually binary trees are populated according to some comparison.  That's not the case here apparently.

Comment: There are almost always more than one tree to be constructed from a level order traversal. There will be no guarantee that the exact tree from which the traversal was created will be produced again.

Comment: @DeepYellow, no, a **binary tree** just has at most 2 children for each node. A **binary search tree** orders the nodes.

Comment: @Bart, I realize that the tree is binary and that no ordering is necessary to meet the definition.  My point is that it's unusual to use a binary structure without some ordering requirement.  I've never come across a practical application, have you?

Comment: a binary *search* tree is not specified; the data may be ordered but it will not be evident from the tree diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
char a[SIZE] = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G}; 
    node* func(int index){
        if(index < SIZE){
            node *tmp = new node();
            tmp->data = a[index];
            tmp->left = func(2*index + 1);
            tmp->right = func(2*index + 2);
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

stacktrace for the tree:

```
                                     A->a[0]
          B->func(2*0 + 1)=[1]                              C->func(2*0 + 2)=[2]
D->func(2*1 + 1)=[3]    E->func(2*1 + 2)=[4]        F->func(2*2 + 1)=[5]     G->func(2*2 + 2)=[6]
```

Answer (score 6):

This is like a **BFS**, so you can use a **queue**.

Notice that you always assign left child and then immediately after that the right child. 
So start with a queue containging the root. At each iteration pop the node from the queue and then read the next two values from the array (or stream). Make the first one the left child of the popped node and push it into the queue. Then make the second one a right child and push it into the queue. And so on until there are no elements left in the array (or stream).

Answer (score 5):

For a full (or filling) binary tree it's easy to convert a level traversal into any traversal because the **children of a node at position `n` are at** `2n` and `2n+1` when the array is 1-indexed and at **`2n+1` and `2n+2` when the array is 0-indexed**.

So you can easily use that formula to turn it into your favorite traversal order for inserting nodes into a tree (like pre-order).

e.g. recursive psuedocode:

```
void fill( TreeNode* node, char a[], int arrayLength, int n ){
    // n is the position of the current "node" in the array
    if( n < arrayLength ){
        node->data = a[n];
        fill( node->left, a, arrayLength, 2n+1 );
        fill( node->right, a, arrayLength, 2n+2 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in an iterative manner fairly easily if you use some additional storage, saving the call overhead of a recursive solution. This is what I would do:

```
node* theTree (char[] a, int arraylength) {
   if (arraylength == 0) return NULL;

   node** nodes = new node*[arraylength];
   nodes[0] = new node();
   nodes[0]->data = a[0];

   for (int i = 0, j = 0; TRUE ; j++) {
      if (++i >= arraylength) return nodes[0];

      nodes[i] = new node();
      nodes[i]->data = a[i];
      nodes[j]->left = nodes[i];

      if (++i >= arraylength) return nodes[0];

      nodes[i] = new node();
      nodes[i]->data = a[i];
      nodes[j]->right = nodes[i];
   }
}
```

Possible improvements include cutting the required memory by a factor of two by overwriting the part of the array of pointers once i > arraylength/2, and possibly preallocating all the nodes at once in an array by themselves (though you need to be careful with deallocation then).

Comment: thanks. the recursion removal is definitely a good thing but not essential to me at present - code compactness will  do for now.